# Salesforce BOX integration with Named Credentials

Tags: apex, api, namedcredentials, box

I am actually trying to use Named Credentials with Auth provider to connect Box API, however when I am trying to authenticate with the box I am stuck. It is taking me to the Salesforce page instead of the Box Authorization page to get the auth code. Am I missing anything?

I have provided redirect URI in box App as in i

**Auth Provider:**

[image]

**BOX App:**
[image]

**Named Credentials:**

[image]

**Authorization Page:**
[image]

Answer (score -2):

best to auth via JWT. I had to make a couple of changes to the python script to get it to work, and you have to have logged in with the OOTB managed package.

https://github.com/kylefernandadams/box-for-salesforce-blueprints

```
import json
import argparse
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
privateKey = ''
def parseCommandLineArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("box_config_path", help="Provide the absolute path to your downloaded Box Application configuration JSON file.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print("Using config json at path: " + args.box_config_path)
    return args.box_config_path

def parseBoxJsonSettings(boxConfigPath):
    with open(boxConfigPath) as jsonFile:
        jsonData = json.load(jsonFile)
        enterpriseID = jsonData['enterpriseID']
        clientID = jsonData['boxAppSettings']['clientID']
        clientSecret = jsonData['boxAppSettings']['clientSecret']
        publicKeyID = jsonData['boxAppSettings']['appAuth']['publicKeyID']
        privateKey = jsonData['boxAppSettings']['appAuth']['privateKey']
        passphrase = jsonData['boxAppSettings']['appAuth']['passphrase']
        print('Found enterprise id: ' + enterpriseID)
        print('Found clientID: ' + clientID)
        print('Found clientSecret: ' + clientSecret)
        print('Found publicKeyID: ' + publicKeyID)

        print('Found passphrase: ' + passphrase)
        print('Found privateKey: ' + privateKey)
        with open('tempKey.txt', 'w') as temp_key:
            temp_key.write(privateKey)
        return passphrase

def convertCryptoKey(passphrase):
    passIn = 'pass:' + passphrase
    results = Popen(['openssl', 'pkcs8', '-topk8', '-nocrypt', '-in', 'tempKey.txt', '-outform', 'PEM', '-passin', passIn], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    newKey = results.communicate()[0]
    print('Found new private key: {}'.format(newKey))
    return newKey

def modifyPkString(newKey):
    withoutFirstLine = newKey.decode('utf-8').split('\n')[1:]
    withoutLastLine = withoutFirstLine[:len(withoutFirstLine)-2]
    privateKey = ''.join(withoutLastLine)
    print('New private key string: ' + privateKey)
    return privateKey

def createBoxJsonSettingsFile(privateKey):
    with open(boxConfigPath) as jsonFile:
        jsonData = json.load(jsonFile)
        jsonData['boxAppSettings']['appAuth']['privateKey'] = privateKey
        with open('sfdc_box_config.json', 'w') as sfdcJsonFile:
            json.dump(jsonData, sfdcJsonFile, indent=2)

boxConfigPath = parseCommandLineArgs()
passphrase = parseBoxJsonSettings(boxConfigPath)
convertedPk = convertCryptoKey(passphrase)
privateKey = modifyPkString(convertedPk)
createBoxJsonSettingsFile(privateKey)
```

Comment: Thank you, my question is why not we authenticate with Named Credentials?

Comment: I got the same error when I was trying to auth that way, not sure.